# How to handle replacing string-literals and why is allocating on heap important?

Tags: c, c-strings

I have heard from a coder that substituting c-string literals causes undefined behaviour.

E.g.:

```
char *a = "111";
a[0] = '2'; //Undefinded behaviour
```

However, I do not find a way around like in the following exercise, where I have to convert 12-hours-time to military time:

```
char* timeConversion(char* s) {
    char* military_time = malloc(9*sizeof(char));
    strncpy(military_time, s,8);
    if(s[8] == 'P'){
       if(s[0]!='1' || s[1]!='2'){
       char hours = 10*(s[0]-'0')+(s[1]-'0');
       hours += 12;
       char tenner = (hours/10) + '0';
       char onner = hours%10 + '0';
       military_time[0] = tenner; //undefined
       military_time[1] = onner;
       }
    } else {
        if(s[0]=='1' && s[1] =='2'){
            military_time[0] = '0';
            military_time[1]= '0';
        }
    }
    return military_time;
}
```

Is there a way to walk around this problem?

Furthermore, I am wondering about the behaviour of this code.
Replacing:

```
char* military_time = malloc(9*sizeof(char));
```

with:

```
char* military_time = "12345678";
```

causes faulty behaviour. I do not think that in the second case the variable gets outdated. Could this be an issue of the site, where I submitted the answer?

Thank you.

Comment: You can allocate memory for your string by using an array: `char military_time[] = "12345678"`. You can then write to it. You still can't return it, because it will be deleted when you leave the function. For that functions usually either return a pointer allocated by `malloc`, or they take a pointer as an argument for the function to write into (for example `fread` does this). But if you're really desperate you can make the array `static`, which means it will exist for as long as the program is active (but then it will also always take up space, even when you don't need it)

Comment: `(s[0]-48)+(s[1]-48)`?  Don't do that.  Use the character value `'0'` instead of `48`.  48 isn't guaranteed to work, `'0'` will always work.  48 is also confusing.

Comment: This always gets easier when you let the caller provide you the storage you need.  It can then decide how to allocate it and, if necessary, how to release it.  It is rarely necessary.  So the signature should be int timeConversion(const char* time, char[] result, size_t resultLen).  Use the int return value to indicate error conditions, like unconvertible time string or result buffer too small.

Comment: `a[0] = '2';` will most like cause a segmentation fault because `a` points to a read only literal.

Comment: Though you can do: `char military_time[] = "12345678";` because this copies the read-only literal to your array, which is modifiable.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY What happens when I do it like shown in the question? Why this does not work?
AndrewHenle: Yes, actually this makes far more sense. Thank you.
HansPassant: Thank you; I did not mind that. However, this was a coding challenge and I cannot change the signature.
PaulOgilvie: How to make it read/write?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie When is something read only?

Comment: @KamilCuk So what to do if you need a mutable string literal? Do not I change the literals in my code? It works fine... (until now)

Comment: I am confused about what do you ask. You code uses `malloc`. If `malloc` calls succeeds, it returns a pointer to a valid memory region. The region's size is 9 bytes, as you requested that many. Then you ask about `char* military_time = "12345678";`. But you code doesn't use any string literals. Do you want to use a string literal? There is no "mutable string literal" - any string literal is immutable. However, a string literal may be used as an initializer for an array. So `char array[9] = "12345678"`. This will initialize the same as `char array[9] = { '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','\0' };`

Comment: Something is read-only when the compiler places it in a read-only data-segment and then the Memory Manage enforces the read-only-ness. For example, if the literal string `"Hello world"` is used in more than one place, then the compiler may use only one occurence of the literal. Clearly that must be protected from being modified in one place so the literal remains the same in the other place.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, I got blocked from StackOverflow to ask further questions. Is something with this question wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have heard from a coder that substituting c-string literals causes undefined behaviour.

Correct, you must not attempt to modify string literals. They are usually placed in read-only area by the compilers.

Pointers to string literals should be declared with `const` to avoid undefined behaviour:

```
char const *a = "111"; 
a[0] = '2';            // Ok: compiler error, because assigment to const
```

> However, I do not find a way around like in the following exercise, ...

`char* military_time = malloc(9*sizeof(char));` does not create string literal, so `military_time[0] = tenner;` is fine.

You can modify memory for which you have allocated memory for:

```
char b[] = "111";      // Create array and initialize with contents copied from literal
b[0] = '2';            // Ok: array can be modified

char *c = malloc(4);   // Create pointer which points to malloc'd area
strcpy(c, "111");      // Copy content from literal
c[0] = '2';            // Ok: pointer points to area that can be modified
```

> ```
> char* military_time = "12345678";
> ```
>
> causes faulty behaviour.

Yes, code is incorrect for the reasons stated above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you maybe just add which type of data (regarding c-string, chars and literals) gets deleted after leaving the method and which must be deleted by hand. Is it true that malloced data can exist after procedures end? I am wondering because I encountered such a problem in the same exercise.

Comment: @TVSuchty That is really a separate question, but to put shortly, all data in `timeConversion` gets deallocated in function exit, *except* one created with `malloc(9*sizeof(char))`. It will live on until you `free()` it, or when program ends and memory gets reclaimed by your operating system.

Comment: So `char * a = "brevb"; return a;`, would not work even if I do not modify anything because `a` gets destroyed?

Comment: @TVSuchty No, that example is fine. Literals like `"brevb"` live as long as your program does. `a` gets destroyed, but it doesn't matter because address of `"brevb"` gets returned in `return a;` before that happens.

Comment: This is so confusing. So the address is copied and then destroyed, while the memory pointed to is still reserved. So why can't I return an array, the return should copy the array and then destroy the inner one

Comment: @TVSuchty Arrays cannot be returned by value directly. This is a flaw in C language, that exists due to historical reasons. If you want to know more, you should search the web or ask a new question. This comment section is not well suited for long conversations.